# Is this series convergent? $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1})\frac{n+3}{n^{2}+n+5} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that this sum converges:

$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1})\frac{n+3}{n^{2}+n+5} $$

My try:

I multiplied  with the conjugate and I got $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(n+3)}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1})(n^{2}+n+5)}$$

How to continue?

Answer (score 0):

Apply limit comparison test with $a_n=\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$

The series converges.

Comment: How do I know which $a_{n}$ to pick?

Comment: @DaniVaja if you look at  the powers of $n$ you can see that the sequence inside the series behaves like $a_n$ in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2(n+3)}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1})(n^{2}+n+5)}\le\frac{4n}{\sqrt n\,n^2}=\frac4{\sqrt n\,n}$$

and by the comparison test and since $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n\,n}\;$ converges, so does our original series (which, of course, is a positive series)

Comment: How do you get $\frac{4n}{n^{2}\cdot \sqrt{n}}$ ?

Comment: Look: $\;n+3\le n+n=2n\;$, and then I diminished the denominator...as simple as that.

Comment: Thank you.I understood!